# Bash Ping Works but SSH fails and Linux server hangs

Tags: linux, hadoop, ssh, rhel

I have a 6 node hadoop cluster installed on RHEL 6.6 . Sometimes (randomly) the servers just freeze. I am able to ping those servers but unable to ssh into them. It works well after a reboot.
Normally I am able to ping and do an ssh into those machines without any issue . Can someone please point out, where and what logs to look into ?

Comment: Can you log into the machines locally (with a monitor and keyboard physically attached) during these events?

Comment: I don't have physical access to these machines , only option is to login via ssh clients .

Comment: Does this always happen around the same time? Any regularity to the events?

Comment: No, also these have been observed over the past few weeks .
Regularity can be said , it happens at least once in 48 hours .